# How to fetch a running service and stop it manually from an activity?

Tags: android, service

In my app I have created a service, suppose `MyService`, and what i want to do is that I only want to run it if i am not inside the app. So when I open my app, I want to check if any instance of `MyService` is running/exists. If found I want to stop it. And when I quit my app will start the service again using intent.

Most of the search results I have found suggests to use `stopService()` method. But i can use that only if I have an intent pointing to that service, right? But the only solution I've found regarding the 'search' process so far suggests using `getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)`. But i get only an `RunningServiceInfo` object through it. How can i use this object to stop the running service?

And if it's not possible, what is the most efficient way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `stopService()` regardless if the service is running or not, so you don't need to check whether it's running or not. If it is, it will be stopped and `stopService()` returns true; otherwise `stopService()` returns false (but it sounds like you don't care about the return value anyway).

See the [documentation for `stopService()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent)).

`getSystemService()` is **not** useful for finding your own service, it's for finding system-level services like the ActivityManager or the AlarmManager.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion helped.